# What type of build strategy is "Laravel 5.2 Quickstart on OpenShift"?

Tags: laravel-5, openshift, web-deployment

I'm new to the whole deployment thing... all my (hobbyist) learning has been done using a local server.... but now it's time to learn the next step.

Got myself an [OpenShift Starter Online] account, bitbucket with my code, and I'm trying to follow this quickstart: https://github.com/luciddreamz/laravel-ex/blob/master/readme.md

My attempts to initate a build end with "Assemble failed" and so I'm into the build configuration etc.

What I want to know is (https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/core_concepts/builds_and_image_streams.html#source-build) .... what type of build is this that I am trying to do? Is this what they call a "Docker build", or is it a "Source-to-Image (S2I) build"? Or is it something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is using a Source-to-Image (S2I) build. If you look at the build strategy in the build configuration, it lists 'Source', which corresponds to S2I. The S2I builder it is using it that for PHP.

Run:

```
oc describe bc
```

to see more details on the build configurations in your project.

Comment: Brilliant! That is a wonderfully succinct and useful answer. Much appreciated.